# How to select text between two lines

Tags: c#, regex

I have a text file like this

```
[user]
name
age
sex
[user]
name
age
sex
[user]
name
age
sex
```

I need to get all the set of users from this text file. one user data set should be like below.

```
[user]
name
age
sex
```

What is the regex I can uses for this purpose.

**Edit:** Sometimes there  are spaces between lines. So no issue to have same line spaces in the result

This is what is tried. but no luck

```
string content = File.ReadAllText(file);
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(content, @"/(?m)[user].*?[user]/");
```

Comment: What have you tried? There isn't any need for regex, just read the file, find the line containing [user] then read that line and the next 3

Comment: Regex does not seem like the right tool for the job.

Comment: Why not just split the lines up and put them in an array? Or better, save the data as a json string

Comment: @Sayes: sometime there are spaces between lines

Comment: I can't see any spaces, either way you just keep reading till you find the next [user]. *What have you tried?* [ask]

Answer (score 4):

Once you've read the file (or part of it) to a string, you can use [String.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf(v=vs.110).aspx).

something like this maybe:

```
String[] result;
result = yourString.Split(new string[] {"[user]"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

This will give you a string (`result`) with each "block". Then use like split with newline as delimiter or something.

Here is a simple, working, example: [Demo](http://ideone.com/mHGEy6)

Answer (score 1):

here is a regex to match the same

```
(?:\[user\]\n(?'name'.*)\n(?'age'.*)\n(?'sex'.*))
```

**test string**

```
[user]
name1
age1
sex1
[user]
name2
age2
sex2
[user]
name3
age3
sex3
```

**result**

MATCH 1

name    [7-12]  `name1`

age [13-17] `age1`

sex [18-22] `sex1`

MATCH 2

name    [30-35] `name2`

age [36-40] `age2`

sex [41-45] `sex2`

MATCH 3

name    [53-58] `name3`

age [59-63] `age3`

sex [64-68] `sex3`

try [demo here](http://regex101.com/r/mD3mA9/1)

**Update**

regex updated to match gaps & optional spaces in lines if necessary

```
(?:\[user\][\n\s]*(?'name'\w*)[\n\s]*(?'age'\w*)[\n\s]*(?'sex'\w*))
```

try [demo here](http://regex101.com/r/mD3mA9/3)

Comment: That currently doesn't handle blank lines (as requested by the OP)

Answer (score 0):

Replace below line. Each item in "content" will have lines from different user.

```
string[] content = File.ReadAllText(file).Split(new string[] {"[user]"},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by using a [streamreader](http://www.dotnetperls.com/streamreader)

```
List<List<string>()> users;
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("file.txt"))
{
    string line;
    List<string> currentUser;
    while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
    {
        if(line == "[user]")
        {
            if(currentUser != null)
                 users.Add(currentUser);
            currentUser = new List<string>{line};
        }
        else
        {
            currentUser.Add(line);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(?ms)\G\[(?<user>.*?)\](?<params>[^\[]+)
```

User in groups "user" and parameters in groups "params"

Answer (score 0):

Would it not be better to use a higher-level `User` class to hold each user's data?

Here's a basic example (with no error handling):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

namespace Demo
{
    sealed class User
    {
        public string Name; // Real code should make these properties.
        public string Age;
        public string Sex;

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return string.Format("Name: {0}, Age: {1}, Sex: {2}", Name, Age, Sex);
        }
    }

    internal static class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] source =
            {
                "[user]",
                "name1",
                "age1",
                "sex1",
                "",
                "[user]",
                "",
                "name2",
                "age2",
                "sex2",
                "",
                "[user]",
                "name3",
                "age3",
                "sex3",
                "",
                "",
                "This should be ignored",
                "So should this",
                "[user]",
                "name4",
                "age4",
                "sex4"
            };

            var nonblankLines = source.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x));

            // If reading from a file, use this instead:
            // var nonBlankLines = File.ReadLines(filename).Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x));

            var users = readUsers(nonblankLines.GetEnumerator());

            Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\n", users)); // Print them out.

            // If for some reason you need a list of users rather than an Enumerable<User>, do this:

            // var listOfUsers = users.ToList();
        }

        static IEnumerable<User> readUsers(IEnumerator<string> input)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                while (input.Current != "[user]")
                    if (!input.MoveNext())
                        yield break;

                input.MoveNext();

                User user = new User();
                user.Name = input.Current;
                input.MoveNext();
                user.Age = input.Current;
                input.MoveNext();
                user.Sex = input.Current;

                yield return user;

                if (!input.MoveNext())
                    yield break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe that's what he is doing once he has read the values? The question is about how to separate the values once they are read, not what to do with them after (allthough I agree that a class is neat here)

Comment: @JohanHjalmarsson I believe that the OP has posted an [XY question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), and what he really wants to do is to get a list of user's names, ages and genders.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
string content = File.ReadAllText(file);
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(content, @"/\[user\].*?(?=\[user\])/s");
```

Regex explanation :)

```
/(?x)       # extended
 \[user\]   # Literal character sequence "[user]"
 .*?        # Any number of anything, newline included (s modifier)
 (?=        # Open positive lookahead group: Asserts match ahead
   \[user\] # Literal character sequence "[user]"
 )          # Closes group.
/s    // s modifier: dot matches new lines.
```

[View a regex demo!](https://regex101.com/r/mD3mA9/4)

With this regex you will get the following two matches from the test case:

> ```
> [user]
> name1
> age1
> sex1
>
> [user]
> name2
> age2
> sex2
> ```

And the best part is that you can change the two `[user]` sequence in your regex to whatever you like and it will still return the correct match:

[image: x]
<sub>(source: [gyazo.com](http://gyazo.com/22c6491848efa6bea5f37bbf14769224.png))</sub>

Answer (score -1):

I suggest saving the data as a json string and then use a json library to convert it to an object or array

Comment: This does not answer the question at all. What if the data is an actual output from a third-party application? It's pointless to convert it to JSON and then convert it to objects programatically.